# Application Error after deploying Meteor 1.0 app on heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, deployment, meteor

I'm trying to deploy a meteor.js app (v 1.0) on heroku using the following buildpack:
https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse
and following along this tutorial:
http://www.growthux.com/ux-html-css-js-growth-hack/installing-meteor-on-heroku

My app is more like a static website, i'm using the database to build a simple back office:
- storing the admin user and image paths which are then dynamically rendered in my templates.

After having created my app on Heroku, set ROOT_URL variable, set the MONGO_URL= variable to my external db on MONGO HQ, (tried mongo lab as well, same problem) and finally push to Heroku, i'm getting this error message when I visit the url:

> Application Error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

So I did:

> 2014-11-10T17:10:23.825922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
>   2014-11-10T17:10:23.825723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
>   2014-11-10T17:10:24.584852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>   2014-11-10T17:10:24.574995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
>   2014-11-10T17:10:26.415257+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cle-meteor.herokuapp.com request_id=ffc312a1-316d-4337-9165-caa492aa7c15 fwd="80.13.242.126" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Not sure if I did something wrong regarding the deployment process, or if I must rethink how my app interact with the database when not running locally.
Any insights?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue, it turned out that I'd left off the "http://" from the ROOT_URL.

Your log messages are fairly generic, is there anything before that?

Here's how I got the meteor "todos" app running on heroku and mongolab.

---

#### Meteor on Heroku

Install meteor

```
curl install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

Add meteor to our path so we can run the "meteor" command from anywhere.

clone an existing meteor app into the heroku folder.

```
meteor create --example todos heroku
```

change to the meteor app's folder.

```
cd heroku
```

I added a package.json file that looks like the following.

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.33",
    "npm":  "1.4.23"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fibers": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

change to our home folder. We want to come back to our previous spot.

```
pushd ~
```

get the heroku client and install it.

```
wget http://assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz
tar -zxvf heroku-client.tgz 
export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/heroku-client/bin
```

Go back to our previous location.

```
popd
```

login to heroku.

```
heroku login
```

> *SKIP THIS PART IF YOU ALREADY HAVE SSH CONFIGURED NICELY WITH HEROKU AND GITHUB*
>
> Add your public SSH key to heroku (if you haven't already done so)
>
> ```
> heroku keys:add ~/keys/heroku_public_key_ssh.txt
> ```
>
> (Manually) Ensure that public SSH key has also been added to your GitHub account.
>
> If you're running ssh-agent, ensure your matching private SSH key is loaded
>
> ```
> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_heroku_github
> ```

Set up our subfolder as a git repository, which we will push to heroku. Substitute your own heroku app name for "mikestodos" below.

```
git init
heroku git:remote -a mikestodos
git add .
git commit -a -m "first deploy"
```

Create a [heroku](http://heroku.com) app. Mine is called mikestodos.

```
heroku create mikestodos --stack cedar --region us --buildpack https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git
```

Create a new [mongolab](http://mongolab.com) database, and a new database user as well.

Set the MONGO_URL for heroku to be our MongoLabs database URL. The format is:

```
heroku config:set MONGO_URL=mongodb://<my_mongouser>:<my_mongodbpassword>@<mymongoserver>:<mymongoport>/<mymongodbname>
```

substitute your own MongoLabs URL below.

```
heroku config:set MONGO_URL=mongodb://mikestodos:<dbpassword>@ds051980.mongolab.com:51980/mikestodos
```

Set the ROOT_URL for our heroku app.

```
heroku config:set ROOT_URL=http://mikestodos.herokuapp.com
```

Now push our app to heroku.

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: `heroku config:set ROOT_URL=http://mikestodos.herokuapp.com` was all i needed! Thanks!

Comment: Well, it won't work anymore due to repetive:

`remote:  !     Push rejected, failure creating release.
remote: ! Push rejected to <app-name>.`

Comment: @Ivan, try adding the mongolab addon to your heroku app.

```heroku addons:add mongolab```

Comment: Further info: it looks like you're encountering this issue:
https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse/issues/13

Comment: Thanks cobberboy, it seems bad practice to do `heroku addons:add mongolab` because it requires verify to my account in heroku that requires credit card which I don't have active credit card. I've deployed heroku apps that connect external database without addons. Almost all buildpacks from github for meteor in heroku still use `heroku addons` :/