# Deploying meteor to Heroku serve : Application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, meteor, meteorite

As a beginner with those tools, i followed tuto i found on the web to help me starting my app.

Here are the exacts commands i runned on ubuntu to deploy the todos example app from meteor and testthe whole thing.

```
meteor create --example todos
cd todos
git init
git add .
git commit -m "my first commit"
heroku create test2-push --stack cedar --buildpack https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git
heroku addons:add mongolab
git remote -v (vérification validité repo)
git push heroku master
```

But I'm having some trouble,as you can see here : http://test2-push.herokuapp.com

When i look at the logs, this is what kind of report i see :

```
    2015-04-01T14:29:25.298089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2015-04-01T14:29:28.779222+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-01T14:29:28.780112+00:00 app[web.1]:                              ^
2015-04-01T14:29:28.785982+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: Router is not defined
2015-04-01T14:29:28.785988+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
2015-04-01T14:29:28.785992+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
2015-04-01T14:29:28.780101+00:00 app[web.1]:                        throw(ex);
2015-04-01T14:29:28.785993+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
2015-04-01T14:29:28.785987+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app/lib/router.js:65:3
2015-04-01T14:29:28.785990+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)
2015-04-01T14:29:28.785985+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app/lib/router.js:1:36
2015-04-01T14:29:28.779799+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
2015-04-01T14:29:29.744095+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2015-04-01T14:29:29.766467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-01T14:34:38.939853+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=4fb9c97d-b6f4-4056-b2d8-bae03d2db625 fwd="195.68.112.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T14:34:40.423408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=9656f317-a5ca-41ba-86f5-1baf492aaae8 fwd="195.68.112.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T14:46:09.239587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=76bfeefc-8632-4e92-835d-76b923e130fe fwd="195.68.112.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T14:46:07.628681+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=24e7d69c-5392-479e-88c1-517a14e49674 fwd="195.68.112.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T15:09:43.185071+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=e3e2e1e3-a1bb-43f9-93b8-b9bbfc4e36e2 fwd="195.68.112.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T15:09:44.651505+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=c4db7ce2-5cb6-4bf8-b742-d282743f9c83 fwd="195.68.112.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T15:24:01.764681+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=eb8e20f8-fd89-40ec-b3c1-663bb4df3d19 fwd="195.68.112.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T15:24:03.176506+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=1f89a73e-31ff-4c64-aad2-d17c0ac1122a fwd="195.68.112.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T15:28:06.635282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-01T15:28:10.577708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2015-04-01T15:28:13.357353+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
2015-04-01T15:28:13.356958+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-01T15:28:13.362147+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app/lib/router.js:65:3
2015-04-01T15:28:13.362149+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
2015-04-01T15:28:13.362152+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
2015-04-01T15:28:13.362153+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
2015-04-01T15:28:13.362142+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: Router is not defined
2015-04-01T15:28:13.362150+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)
2015-04-01T15:28:13.362146+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app/lib/router.js:1:36
2015-04-01T15:28:13.357583+00:00 app[web.1]:                              ^
2015-04-01T15:28:13.357581+00:00 app[web.1]:                        throw(ex);
2015-04-01T15:28:14.241298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2015-04-01T15:28:14.261373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-01T16:55:38.180103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-01T16:55:41.740295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2015-04-01T16:55:45.494145+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
2015-04-01T16:55:45.493712+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-01T16:55:45.494389+00:00 app[web.1]:                              ^
2015-04-01T16:55:45.500227+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)
2015-04-01T16:55:45.500223+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app/lib/router.js:65:3
2015-04-01T16:55:45.500228+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
2015-04-01T16:55:45.494367+00:00 app[web.1]:                        throw(ex);
2015-04-01T16:55:45.500218+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: Router is not defined
2015-04-01T16:55:45.500222+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app/lib/router.js:1:36
2015-04-01T16:55:45.500225+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
2015-04-01T16:55:45.500230+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
2015-04-01T16:55:46.333405+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-01T16:55:46.323223+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2015-04-01T18:03:57.467111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=d3c85c9b-f228-4d24-b429-cef66b57061f fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T18:04:00.465222+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=8d8bbe21-dffc-4a96-a566-bb4b536c0527 fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T18:23:57.920020+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=5f6edcfa-a39f-43b1-8c29-86abfcccc0d0 fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T18:23:58.666355+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=e9a4dd11-8a38-4fbb-a291-1c483651d476 fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T18:23:58.976873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=b1dd5f1c-3fdc-4a56-b887-46037596c9df fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T18:27:20.460565+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=0ff2c2d0-c964-4215-837c-94c4ee13c668 fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T18:27:21.520543+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=544b0710-dbb2-4869-bd67-4e3262a72f4c fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T18:27:23.130196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=b43c1cd2-e735-4043-bc25-8eaf46dd4874 fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T18:53:02.827733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=9d81d4e8-cb68-4690-961e-d55876d60eab fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T18:53:04.616451+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=07b3e91c-3699-41bb-8998-e42b8e25b5af fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T18:53:05.814028+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=c53fe109-d3d3-4b04-b6b6-2e8da78dbdb1 fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T19:20:25.110777+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=5c6f7a16-a522-4626-8d27-d9a9a64d3627 fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T19:20:25.954811+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=92731058-5a9f-429a-8092-a14e0c74316f fwd="82.234.60.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T19:27:30.010755+00:00 heroku[api]: Set ROOT_URL config vars by davidpanart@gmail.com
2015-04-01T19:27:30.010755+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by davidpanart@gmail.com
2015-04-01T19:27:30.282881+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-01T19:27:32.734761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2015-04-01T19:27:35.454118+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
2015-04-01T19:27:35.453619+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-01T19:27:35.473776+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app/lib/router.js:1:36
2015-04-01T19:27:35.454360+00:00 app[web.1]:                              ^
2015-04-01T19:27:35.473769+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: Router is not defined
2015-04-01T19:27:35.473783+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
2015-04-01T19:27:35.473779+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
2015-04-01T19:27:35.473780+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)
2015-04-01T19:27:35.454321+00:00 app[web.1]:                        throw(ex);
2015-04-01T19:27:35.473782+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
2015-04-01T19:27:35.473777+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app/lib/router.js:65:3
2015-04-01T19:27:36.303841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2015-04-01T19:27:36.350695+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-01T19:27:36.351363+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-01T19:27:40.078073+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2015-04-01T19:27:42.795297+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
2015-04-01T19:27:42.801101+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)
2015-04-01T19:27:42.801098+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app/lib/router.js:65:3
2015-04-01T19:27:42.801103+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
2015-04-01T19:27:42.794734+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-01T19:27:42.795670+00:00 app[web.1]:                        throw(ex);
2015-04-01T19:27:42.801093+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: Router is not defined
2015-04-01T19:27:42.795908+00:00 app[web.1]:                              ^
2015-04-01T19:27:42.801096+00:00 app[web.1]:     at app/lib/router.js:1:36
2015-04-01T19:27:42.801099+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
2015-04-01T19:27:42.801104+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
2015-04-01T19:27:43.610749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2015-04-01T19:27:43.621555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-01T19:28:07.734024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=8dd496d4-7f43-4e42-a332-89b4c8ab7f23 fwd="88.142.102.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T19:28:08.550440+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=b3815840-92d9-4bf3-9717-86c79bad5ef4 fwd="88.142.102.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T19:28:11.358782+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=3e796eea-53e1-4cc0-b439-9a4a07c4d639 fwd="88.142.102.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-01T19:28:12.506991+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test2-push.herokuapp.com request_id=1fecde7f-27ba-460f-b5da-387eac86e13f fwd="88.142.102.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

It seems that i got several problem with fibers and router, often getting the exit status 8, but i do not understand a lot about that logs, and haven't found yet any explanation on the web.

Would someone have an explanation for me ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Its seems like it can't find the iron:router package, take a look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867881/application-error-after-deploying-meteor-1-0-app-on-heroku) wich guide you to deploy the todos app into heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had possibly the same issue.  I completely fixed mine by setting the buildpack differently:
heroku buildpack:set https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git -a YOUR_APPNAME